# Pi Filter Design

Tags: power-supply, filter, emc, low-pass, emi-filtering

I'm new to design, all the help is appreciated.

I'm drawing VCC12V from a external board for this application. I'm facing issues of EMI/EMC and voltage level of VCC5V is not that stable as expected to be.

So I'm planning to implement a PI Filter in front of switching regulator LM2576.

Incoming supply is 12V, 830mAand I wanted to remove any AC elements and noise from incoming supply. As I am not familiar with filter design can you help me with this?

Sorry for my English. Not my first language.

[image]

Comment: Alex - Hi, Please [edit] the question and add details & relevant scope traces: (a) Describe & quantify the "issues of EMI/EMC". (b) Why do you believe an input Pi filter is the solution to (a)? (c) Describe & quantify how VCC5V is "not that stable". (d) As with any SMPS, the PCB layout affects its behaviour (e.g. output noise etc.). Therefore please add photos of the actual h/w and images of the PCB layout from the EDA s/w. (e) Which exact LM2576 are you using? (f) There are many fake LM2576 devices sold online. Do you believe yours is genuine? Why? || Thanks.

Comment: How have you confirmed that the problems are there by measuring them? If it's conducted noise from the AC then you can measure it with a scope. And in which case a line filter on the AC input would be the correct solution.

Comment: You need to be very careful with the regulator layout for these parts (well, for any switch regulator, but simple switcher in particular), your EMC problems might be caused by a bad layout. Also, you do get what you pay for... I wouldn't recommend using these parts for anything sensitive like RF supplies.